# show "Save as" window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ajax, .net-3.5, popup

How can i show a Save as window in asp.net and C#...

This is similar to the one that opens for uploading but that window is the open file...

I am not looking to save only one file...like

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
```

can i make it ung ajax... please help... samples or suggestions..

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "not looking to save only one file"? Do you want to send several files in one response?

Comment: There's some confusion here, please help us out. Some of it is my fault. Is this what you want:

1) User clicks on a link (or a button), expecting to receive several files.
2) Several "Save As" windows appear, one for each file.

Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you don't have any way of interacting with the file system using javascript from inside the browser.  I would imagine that this would be a fairly large security hole if you could.  The best I can suggest is to package up your files in a zip file then send that in a response with the content disposition set to attachment, then let the browser handle it for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question - he wants to have a single page download several files, prompting for each one. If you don't think it's possible, just say so.

Answer (score -1):

In your page:

```
<iframe src="getFile.aspx?id=1"/>
<iframe src="getFile.aspx?id=2/>
```

Then inside getFile.aspx

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);
```

(Note: never tried this myself...)

Comment: This would open multiple "Save as" dialogs, one for each file, which is what he is trying to avoid -- see his response to the comment on the question.